# How Apple Photos collectionview pinch zoom works?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

If you go to Apple Photos and do pinch zoom you can zoom in/out to change the number of columns in the grid. I assume it uses `UICollectionView`, however, I have no idea how it obtains this animation.

It's not difficult to change the number of columns in UICollectionView programmatically, I don't quite get the animation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any answer would be a guess. It looks like they watch the gesture and are ready with a whole set of collection views with different layouts and just cross dissolve to the next in the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the gesture triggers a new layout. There's a whole class dedicated to switching between layouts gracefully: [`UICollectionViewTransitionLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewtransitionlayout). The docs say in part:

> You can use UICollectionViewTransitionLayout as-is or subclass it to
> provide specialized behavior for your app. A common use for transition
> layouts is to create interactive transitions, such as those that are
> driven by gesture recognizers or touch events.

Unlike a regular time-based animation, the transition between layouts is driven by a `transitionProgress` property that you update, so the transition can easily track a gesture. You can see exactly that kind of thing happening in Photos: if you alternate between pinching and zooming, the transition tracks that by going back and forth.

It's possible, perhaps likely, that Photos uses a subclass of `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` in order to provide a more polished user experience, but if you're looking to emulate what Photos does, I think this class is the right way to start.

Comment: That is very helpful thank you for the insights. I've seen an example of transitioning between layouts where they have different sizes. Apple goes a step further and somehow being able to do fade effect and some cells clipping off the screen. If you have any insights at all would love to hear it.

Comment: If you want to include fading, use the `transitionProgress` property to drive the `alpha` property of the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` associated with the layout that's fading in or out.